# Running Play 2.4.x Locally Yields: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

While trying to start my Play app locally I am getting a

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1

exception followed by a

> (*:playRun) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

message.  I can see in the trace the invalid port arg being sent `(..../Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar" xsbt.boot.Boot "~run -1")` but cannot find where to update this argument.  There has to be somewhere to override default values.  And...  No matter what is in the application.conf (http.port) or what I pass on the command line -Dhttp.port I still get the same error.  Any info would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: Please, write here command that you use to start app.

Comment: Thank you, but sadly this doesn't solve the problem in any case :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same exception and I was in touch with the IntelliJ support team, and got the message it was a bug, because of the https protocol in the open browser field. The url parser cannot handle https and thus not extract the port number.

Bug report here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9971

Comment: Thank you, but sadly this doesn't solve the problem in any case :/